# Is there any way to organize my videos/music files to folders?

Tags: 8.0, music, video

I tried to copy many video files to my Windows Phone 8 device in different folders. But, when I open `Music + Videos` app it is showing all the videos in one list. Is there any way see it in group based upon the folder it is put up. If any other app available to achieve this, that is also fine.

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible - have you tried Playlists? [I commented on a similar question also](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/2176/video-folders-moved-from-windows-8-to-windows-phone-8-with-explorer). Basically, the phone reads all files and folder then displays a flat alphabetical jump-list of Artists, Songs, Albums, etc.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate. Does the other question not answer yours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to explain what is happening, allow me to go in to a little bit of background as to how Windows Phone handles media files.

When you drag and drop files from your computer on to the phone, while it may appear that you are creating an identical structure on your phone, there is in fact more processing taking place in the background. When you connect your phone to the computer, it is not mounted as simple external storage. It is instead mounted as an [MTP device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol).

When you move a bunch of files on to the phone, for each file, the phone automatically creates a metadata file in a hidden folder.

When you try to view/play the media files on your phone, the phone actually looks for the metadata files that link to the actual media files. The metadata files have no directory structure and hence you see your media appear as one long list.

Rather than going around messing with any of this, I reckon your best bet is to use Playlists (as suggested by @NeilTurner).

Comment: I think playlist is the only option left for me. But, I don't understand why they are making it so complicated with these metadata and all these stuffs. Ya it is good to show in one list, there is one way to see all your videos in a shot. But, in parallel can't they show up a UI to show the plane folder structure as well. That makes things easy as you copy in files from computer most of the time.

Comment: You can add your feedback here (official Windows Phone forum): http://windowsphone.uservoice.com

Comment: thanks for the feedback link. I just voted for a file manager, that can solve this. :)